# payload of an email in string format, python

Tags: python, string, email, payload

I got payload as a string instance using `get_payload()` method. But I want my payload in a way where I could access it word by word
I tried several things like `as_string() method, flatten() method, get_charset() method` , but every time there is some problem.

I got my payload using the following code

```
import email
from email import *
f=open('mail.txt','r')
obj=email.parser.Parser()
fp=obj.parse(f)
payload=fp.get_payload()
```

Comment: You dont mention what problems you actually have

Comment: Importing twice is useless. You should delete the second line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually I am new with this language
What I need is to get a list, so that I could get access each word of that list

Comment: @rubik - He should actually replace both lines with just `import email.parser`

Comment: @puneet - Based on my answer, once you have the actual message, you can just do:  `str(message).split()` to split it into a list separated on whitespace.

Comment: @puneet, Can you post the content of mail.txt?

Comment: I think the get_payload() method is really designed poorly. It returns such a mixed variation of results. You can get a list of message instances, or a single message instance, or just a string. It really just should always return a list of message instances even if its a single element. Im not a fan of variable return signatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested your snippet with a couple of my own raw emails. Works fine...

get_payload() returns either a list or string, so you need to check that first

```
if isinstance(payload, list):
    for m in payload:
        print str(m).split()

else:
    print str(m).split()
```

**Edit**

Per our discussion, your issue was that you were not checking is_multipart() on the fp object, which actually is a message instance. If fp.is_multipart() == True, then get_payload() will return a list of message instances. In your case, based on your example mail message, it was NOT multipart, and fp was actually the object you were interesting in.

Comment: only the else loop is working,
and when I try to change it into string, it says that payload is a message instance

Comment: @puneet - updated my answer. For a message instance you can call get_payload() on that to get just the body content.

Comment: yes, it working after replacing "list" with "object" but still I am not able to get words seperated, now its showing me each character in a different line with the following code
if isinstance(payload, object):
    for m in payload:
        print str(m)

Comment: Thats completely wrong. Everything in python is an instance of object. object is the base class for all new classes, so you are just forcing a string to run through that section of code. Its printing each character because you are looping over a string and printing each charter. I have updated yet again to try and get you the output you want. It would be best to try and check for every possible output: list of instances, list of strings, string, instance but I dont want to type out an entire robust amount of code for ya when you should be able to get the gist from this.

Comment: I tried that, but even this was showing me each character at a different index

Comment: post your mail.txt so I can specifically address your message example

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5963/discussion-between-jdi-and-puneet)

Comment: I got my payload as a string as my fp was not multipart
If it could have been a multipart, it would have returned a list of strings
so now I can just use the following code 

    payload=fp.get_payload()
    abc=payload.split(" ")

it gives me the output as follows
['good', 'day\nhttp://72.167.116.186/image/bdfedx.php?iqunin=3D41\n\n', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Sun,', '18', 'Dec', '2011', .....]
thanks to jdi :)
p.s. couldnt post it as an answer, as there was some restriction with points

Answer (score 0):

I got my payload as a string as my fp was not multipart
If it could have been a multipart, it would have returned a list of strings
so now I can just use the following code

```
payload=fp.get_payload()
abc=payload.split(" ")
```

it gives me the output as follows
['good', 'day\nhttp://72.167.116.186/image/bdfedx.php?iqunin=3D41\n\n', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Sun,', '18', 'Dec', '2011', '10:53:43\n_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***\n"She', 'wiped', 'him', 'dry', 'with', 'soft', 'flannel,', 'and', 'gave', 'him', 'some', 'clean,', 'dry', 'clothes,=\n', 'and', 'made', 'him', 'very', 'comfortable', 'again."', '(c)', 'Lyrica', 'wa946758\n']

thanks to jdi :)
p.s. couldnt post it as an answer yesterday,  as there was some restriction with points