# Applying Regular Expression To An Instance - From Email

Tags: python, regex, email

I'm using the imaplib module to log into my gmail account and retrieve emails.
This gives me alot of information aswell as the to/from/subject/body text. According to
type(msg) th object returned is a instance.

My regex wont work when I apply it to the msg object as it expects a string, and this is obviously an instance so doesn't work.

Example of regex to identify the date which works fine when I just give it a string:

```
    match = re.search(r"Time:\s(([0-2]\d):([0-5]\d))", text) # validates hour and minute in a 24 hour clock
```

So three questions really:
1.) am I going about this the right way or is there a better way to do it?
2.) how can I apply my regex to this 'instance' informtion so I can identify the date/time etc
3.) how can I just retrieve the email body?

```
result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")

raw_email = data[0][1]

email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)

msg = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
msg.get_payload()
```

Thank you again

Comment: I havent used the imaplib in a bit but the msg instance can either be converted to a string with str(msg) or it has attributes to return the msg

Comment: I'm new to python but when I do type(msg) it returns <type'instance'>? Is that not a type?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this problem might be really close to another question I had answered:
[payload of an email in string format, python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553650/payload-of-an-email-in-string-format-python/8553742#8553742)

The main problem for the other person was that get_payload() can return multipart objects which you have to check for. Its not always just a string.

Here is the snippet from the other question about how to handle the object you get from get_payload():

```
if isinstance(payload, list):
    for m in payload:
        print str(m).split()

else:
    print str(m).split()
```

Also, you can review the actual extended conversation that I had with the OP of that question here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5963/discussion-between-jdi-and-puneet

Comment: I think you could be right but I don't really understand how to solve the problem. So how do I just access the body/from/subject etc if the msg is a multipart object?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the body of the email can be accessed via the payload[0], as payload is a list while the msg variable was an instance. I then just converted it to a string with a simple

```
payload = msg.get_payload()
body = payload[0]
str_body = str(body)
```

Thanks for your help again